# How can I prevent a js function from running when a searched after getElementById cannot be found?

Tags: javascript

I have a script that adds a top scroll on a horizontal div. The script has to add it on up to 10 different divs. (From mainplh_boAutoOddsTable1_divScrollContainer to mainplh_boAutoOddsTable10_divScrollContainer)

To do this I call the script 10 times (below are the first 3 examples). However if one of the divs are missing it breaks the script.

```
doublescroll(document.getElementById('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable1_divScrollContainer'));
doublescroll(document.getElementById('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable2_divScrollContainer'));
doublescroll(document.getElementById('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable3_divScrollContainer'));
```

If for example mainplh_boAutoOddsTable1_divScrollContainer cannot be found it breaks my Javascript. How can I solve this? For example prevent from the function from running if it cannot find that div element?

Error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollWidth' of null
```

This is the full javascript:

```
function doublescroll(element) {
        var scrollbar= document.createElement('div');
        scrollbar.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        scrollbar.style.overflow= 'auto';
        scrollbar.style.overflowY= 'hidden';
        scrollbar.style.width= '506px';
        scrollbar.firstChild.style.width= element.scrollWidth+'px';
        scrollbar.firstChild.style.paddingTop= '1px';
        scrollbar.firstChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\xA0'));
        scrollbar.onscroll= function() {
            element.scrollLeft= scrollbar.scrollLeft;
        };
        element.onscroll= function() {
            scrollbar.scrollLeft= element.scrollLeft;
        };
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(scrollbar, element);
    }

doublescroll(document.getElementById('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable1_divScrollContainer'));
doublescroll(document.getElementById('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable2_divScrollContainer'));
doublescroll(document.getElementById('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable3_divScrollContainer'));
doublescroll(document.getElementById('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable4_divScrollContainer'));
doublescroll(document.getElementById('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable5_divScrollContainer'));
doublescroll(document.getElementById('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable6_divScrollContainer'));
doublescroll(document.getElementById('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable7_divScrollContainer'));
doublescroll(document.getElementById('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable8_divScrollContainer'));
doublescroll(document.getElementById('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable9_divScrollContainer'));
doublescroll(document.getElementById('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable10_divScrollContainer'));
```

Comment: You can check for existence before or after calling the function.

Comment: I would like to add that any solution that fixes the issue is acceptable. Including stopping the script from throwing the error when an element is not found.

Comment: all of the answers so far solve your issue. if you want the whole thing to stop, you will need to check a return value from your function, wrap all your functions calls into a looping construct and quit on any return of false.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Difficult to select an answer :) I have selected the one with the exact solution that I have implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making your code a little more robust:

```
function doublescroll(element_id) {
        var element = document.getElementById(element_id);
        if (!element) return;
        var scrollbar= document.createElement('div');
        scrollbar.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        scrollbar.style.overflow= 'auto';
        scrollbar.style.overflowY= 'hidden';
        scrollbar.style.width= '506px';
        scrollbar.firstChild.style.width= element.scrollWidth+'px';
        scrollbar.firstChild.style.paddingTop= '1px';
        scrollbar.firstChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\xA0'));
        scrollbar.onscroll= function() {
            element.scrollLeft= scrollbar.scrollLeft;
        };
        element.onscroll= function() {
            scrollbar.scrollLeft= element.scrollLeft;
        };
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(scrollbar, element);
    }

doublescroll('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable1_divScrollContainer');
doublescroll('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable2_divScrollContainer');
doublescroll('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable3_divScrollContainer');
doublescroll('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable4_divScrollContainer');
doublescroll('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable5_divScrollContainer');
doublescroll('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable6_divScrollContainer');
doublescroll('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable7_divScrollContainer');
doublescroll('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable8_divScrollContainer');
doublescroll('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable9_divScrollContainer');
doublescroll('mainplh_boAutoOddsTable10_divScrollContainer');
```

Answer (score 4):

Do a check for the existence of `element` in your function:

```
function doublescroll(element) {
        if(!element)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var scrollbar= document.createElement('div');
        scrollbar.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        scrollbar.style.overflow= 'auto';
        scrollbar.style.overflowY= 'hidden';
        scrollbar.style.width= '506px';
        scrollbar.firstChild.style.width= element.scrollWidth+'px';
        scrollbar.firstChild.style.paddingTop= '1px';
        scrollbar.firstChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\xA0'));
        scrollbar.onscroll= function() {
            element.scrollLeft= scrollbar.scrollLeft;
        };
        element.onscroll= function() {
            scrollbar.scrollLeft= element.scrollLeft;
        };
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(scrollbar, element);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If the element is not found by `getElementById`, `null` is returned.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.getElementById

Do a check in your function at the beginning.

```
function doublescroll(element) {
    if(element === null) {
        return;
    }

    //rest of code here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for the element at the start of the function:

```
if(!element)
{
    return;
}
```